# maven build is taking too long to stop in Jenkins even though build is successful

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. Somehow I managed to install it and configure my Maven Project in that. But I am facing some issue for which I didn't find any solution. Please help me through that. Here is my question.

Once I click on the build Now it will start executing the maven commands. Build is successful also. But it is not stopping and showing the output of the build like build success or build failure. Here is the screenshot how it is showing in console output.
[You can see the buffering in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJkOj.png)

Here is the one more screenshot where it will show the status of the build.
[#12 is the current build which got stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpSi7.png)

I tried to abort it by placing time limit. But the problem with this is it will not show the build success or build failure. It will show build is aborted.
Anyone please help me through this.